# Why do RI=RL equal in maximum power transfer theorm?

Tags: power-supply, power, resistors, resistance, power-electronics

I know mathematical proof I need explanation. Why this happen.That doesn't make any sense to me.I know that in series connection current (I)is same.But here  current flow is changing with different value of variable resistance. Why this happen.Please explain someone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the following schematic, V1 is a fixed voltage source and R1 is a 100 ohm resistor which is used to control the voltage across the transistor as the current in the circuit varies because of the change in the resistance of Q1.

V2 is a time-variable voltage source used to control the transistor's drain-to-source resistance, and the transistor's power dissipation is plotted as a function of its resistance.

The green trace shows the current through Q1, the red trace shows the power dissipated by R1, and the yellow trace shows the power dissipated by Q1.

The yellow trace's peak indicates where maximum **transfer** of power occurs, and is equal to the power R1 dissipates at that point, so Q1's drain-to-source resistance and the resistance of R1 must be equal at that point.

The LTspice schematic list follows the schematic just in case you'd like to see more of what's going on in the circuit.

[image]

```
Version 4
SHEET 1 880 680
WIRE 64 48 -16 48
WIRE 384 48 144 48
WIRE 384 96 384 48
WIRE -16 144 -16 48
WIRE 336 176 272 176
WIRE 272 208 272 176
WIRE -16 336 -16 224
WIRE 272 336 272 288
WIRE 272 336 -16 336
WIRE 384 336 384 192
WIRE 384 336 272 336
WIRE -16 400 -16 336
FLAG -16 400 0
SYMBOL voltage -16 128 R0
WINDOW 123 0 0 Left 2
WINDOW 39 0 0 Left 2
SYMATTR InstName V1
SYMATTR Value 100
SYMBOL res 160 32 R90
WINDOW 0 0 56 VBottom 2
WINDOW 3 32 56 VTop 2
SYMATTR InstName R1
SYMATTR Value 100
SYMBOL nmos 336 96 R0
SYMATTR InstName M1
SYMATTR Value BSS123
SYMBOL voltage 272 192 R0
WINDOW 3 24 96 Invisible 2
WINDOW 123 0 0 Left 2
WINDOW 39 0 0 Left 2
SYMATTR InstName V2
SYMATTR Value PULSE(0 5 0 1)
TEXT -10 360 Left 2 !.tran 2
```

Answer (score 5):

If the load is zero (i.e. a short circuit) then the power in the load is zero since the voltage across the load is zero.

If the load is infinite (i.e. an open circuit) then there is zero current through the load and the power in the load is, again, zero.

Between these two extremes, the load power must come to a maximum and we have to use calculus to determine exactly where that maximum lies.

Comment: Very Nice Explanation.